# GDI Draw Rectange Array, the first line rectangle can't be drawn

Tags: c#, graphics, gdi

I have a map data which will draw a map like this:

```
private int[,] mapData = new int[11, 25]
{
   { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4 },
   { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 },
   { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 },
   { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 },
   { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 },
   {  0,  1,  1,  2,  1,  3,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3 },
   { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,  1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 },
   { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,  2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 },
   { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,  1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 },
   { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,  1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 },
   { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,  3,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 },
};
```

And here is my render logic:

```
e.Graphics.Clear(Color.Gray);
float renderRectWidth = (float)pictureBox1.Width / (float)25;
float renderRectHeight = (float)pictureBox1.Height / (float)11;
for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 25; j++)
    {
        int element = mapData[i, j];

        Color c;
        if (element == 0)
        {
            c = Color.Black;
        }
        else if (element == 1)
        {
            c = Color.Blue;
        }
        else if (element == 2)
        {
            c = Color.Orange;
        }
        else if (element == 3)
        {
            c = Color.Green;
        }
        else if (element == 4)
        {
            c = Color.Red;
        }
        else
        {
            c = Color.AliceBlue;
        }
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(c), startPoint.X, startPoint.Y, renderRectWidth, renderRectHeight);
        startPoint.X = startPoint.X + renderRectWidth;
    }
    startPoint.X = 0;
    startPoint.Y = (i + 1) * renderRectHeight;
}
```

It will cause the following result, so my question is: why the first line can't be drawn, but other lines can be drawn?

[image: Draw result]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd rewrite it as:

```
private int[,] mapData = 
{
   { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4 },
   { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 },
   { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 },
   { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 },
   { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 },
   {  0,  1,  1,  2,  1,  3,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3 },
   { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,  1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 },
   { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,  2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 },
   { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,  1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 },
   { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,  1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 },
   { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,  3,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 },
};

private Point startPoint;
private Dictionary<Color, SolidBrush> brushes = new Dictionary<Color, SolidBrush>();
private Color[] colors = { Color.Black, Color.Blue, Color.Orange, Color.Green, Color.Red };

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    startPoint = new Point(0, 0);
    e.Graphics.Clear(Color.Gray);
    float renderRectWidth = (float)pictureBox1.Width / (float)mapData.GetLength(1);
    float renderRectHeight = (float)pictureBox1.Height / (float)mapData.GetLength(0);            
    for (int i = 0; i <= mapData.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= mapData.GetUpperBound(1); j++)
        {
            int element = mapData[i, j];                    
            Color c = (element == -1) ? Color.AliceBlue : colors[element];
            if (!brushes.ContainsKey(c))
            {
                brushes.Add(c, new SolidBrush(c));
            }
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brushes[c], startPoint.X, startPoint.Y, renderRectWidth, renderRectHeight);
            startPoint.X = startPoint.X + (int)renderRectWidth;
        }
        startPoint.X = 0;
        startPoint.Y = startPoint.Y + (int)renderRectHeight;
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Nice! Do you know what the problem my render logic is?

Comment: My best GUESS is you had "startPoint" as a form level variable and did not reset it before rendering each time so the very first line would draw at the last computed "y" value, which would be the last row.  So it would draw the first line in the last row,  but then subsequently get painted over afterwards so it'd be hard to see what was happening.  Note that I use `startPoint = new Point(0, 0);` at the beginning of the render routine.